# Angular with Microdata

Tags: angularjs, seo, angularjs-ng-repeat, schema.org, microdata

Does Microdata work with dynamic Angular `ng-repeat` items?

Can I use it as:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" ng-repeat="item in items">
    …
</div>
```

Comment: hello ... did you ever get a solid answer on this ?? ... it seems to me that the google robots probably don't hang around your webpage for a second or two while angular goes through its compile phases ...

Comment: I asked this question again: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450989/will-schema-markup-placed-within-ng-repeats-be-read-by-search-engines)

Answer (score 0):

I have found [schema validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) which, for my site actually shows angular expressions:

```
...
datePublished  {{lvl_project['year']}}
name          "{{lvl_project['title']}}"
keywords       {{lvl_project['tools'].join(',')}}
...
```

Furthermore, it does NOT show all of the `ng-repeat`-generated elements.

This seems to me like a strong indication that the google-bot did *not* see the angular-generated elements and their values, but there could be more to the issue that I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use...it will work on all (but use if all comes in same category).

Comment: What do you mean "if all comes in same category"? I have 100 categories, and then in each category ads, with pagination.

Comment: Category means here is Schema category, all things you offer come in product or there may be more relevant option in schema.