# Will Microdata markup placed within ng-repeats be read by search engines?

Tags: angularjs, seo, javascript-framework, schema.org, microdata

*NOTE:* My question is identical to the *unanswered* question: [Angular schema SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458214/angular-schema-seo/32560776).

---

My question is more of a *search engine* question than an angular question.

Basically this question asks: do search engine bots hang around your webpage for a second or two while some client-side js library (such as angular) re-constructs the dom and then read the completed dom, as angular does during the compile phases when handling ng-repeat directives.

```
<div itemscope 
     itemtype  = "http://schema.org/Movie"
   >
   <span ng-repeat = "movie in movies"
         itemprop  = "name"
     >
     {{movie}}
   </span>
</div>
```

So will google bot ever read every `itemprop=name` for every movie generated by this ng-repeat?

---

I have found [schema validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) which, for my site (*which is unrelated to the example html above*), actually still shows the angular expressions:

```
...
datePublished  {{lvl_project['year']}}
name          "{{lvl_project['title']}}"
keywords       {{lvl_project['tools'].join(',')}}
...
```

Furthermore, it did *not* show the `ng-repeat`-generated elements.

This seems to me like a strong indicator that the google-bot did *not* see the angular-generated elements and their values, but there could be more to the issue that I don't know.

Comment: For Google Search: [Does Schema.org markup work if markup is dynamically built with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29064209/1591669)

Comment: I'll defer to @unor but TTBOMK the full JSON-LD or micordata structure must be inline in either <head> or <body>. There may be one exception. Google AMP supports `mustache`. Google shows examples where `mustache` phrases load external data that is displayed in the Google CDN. I've never done this; only read about it. But it seems to be an example that fits your "hang around" question.